# Geometry nodes scale instance from Z axis

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm brand new on Geo Nodes. I am having hard times figuring out how to scale my distributed points on faces from normals? I've learned how to distribute them but for some reason i cant find how to scale them the same way so it does a fading scaled points.
[image: Distributed Points on Faces from Z]

[image: Distribute Points on Faces node]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff *is* tricky to get the hang of, IMO. It's not immediately obvious from the interface which attributes are on which domains of which geometry.(The *Viewer* node can help)

You somehow have to get the (Object-Space) Z-component of the `Normal` of the incoming Geometry into an attribute that can be picked up and used to scale your icosphere instances. Points don't have a `Normal`, but they do have a `Radius` :

[image]

(Above) The greenish nodes do the selection, as you have, in your tree. The red nodes:

- Capture the Z-component of the `Normal` of incoming Geometry...
- ... so it can be given to the `Radius` of the points on which instances are to be generated...
- ... then at the point of creation, a function of the point's `Radius` can be used to scale the instances generated on them:

[image]

In some cases, attributes have to be transferred, rather than captured and used to set a convenient existing attribute... see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245858/35559), or others which address the same problem.

Comment: Wow indeed! This is tricky! I would never have found all of this. It will definitely help me a lot for learning geo nodes. Thank you very for you much for your answer and explanation. I'm really grateful!