# Bring a texture from Shading to Geometry Nodes

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I have a procedurally created (and continuously being tweaked) texture in shading tab used for material stuff. I'd like to bring(link) that texture to my geometry nodes tab where I use it to scatter stuff.
I previously asked about [how to get something from Geometry Nodes to Shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248236/send-geometry-nodes-value-into-shading-tab), and it was solved using the empty socket of group output. But now that I want to go the other way, there's not that output socket.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this:

[image]

Just use the Attribute Sample Texture, then choose your texture and insert "UVMap" (the name of your UVMap) into Mapping and some name (i took dens) and use this e.g. as the density attribute.

[image]

[image]

> NOTE: the Attribute Sample Texture node is a legacy node and is
> removed in 3.0.0 and later versions.

Comment: It would really be cool to have a workable solution here - I mean, working in current and upcoming Blender versions. This was a nice attribute node, I wonder if there are plans to get something similar in the future. I could also imagine not only procedural textures but all images as "weight maps" or something like that, just like you can use images as alpha maps in the shader editor etc. I would like images as "selection maps".

Comment: i hope/think it will come....  ;)