# How to change of the color of instances placed around a sphere based on their location

Tags: instances, geometry-nodes

I am new to blender and want to create a series of light sources that are scattered across a spherical mesh. I then want to animate the colors of the lights so that it looks like the colors are sweeping around the lights.

So far, I have the instances spread out on the ico-sphere. What do I have to do now to get the instances to change color based on their position on the sphere? Preferably I would like the color to revolve around the sphere.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Look at this post " https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248236/send-geometry-nodes-value-into-shading-tab " and play around with "geometry proximity node" or this " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f2HXGtVUpo&ab_channel=WannesMalfait ", if it doesn't look like you want it to :). I will post the solution in a few hours, when have time to write it.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to "LuckyOne"s solution. As I see it you want the colors to rotate around the sphere origin. The base idea is still the same, make geometry nodes output some values, that you can then use in shading nodes.

Example:
[image]

[image]

Which produces:

[image]

The problem is the points at the top are closer together so they do not follow right colors. (But it is still a nice effect, which might be what you want).

The second way to get a similar result is to create a Cartesian to spherical  conversion coordinate system node. This way you can get exact angle from origin which produces the following effect.

[image]

The nodes for this example are slightly more complex:

[image]

Where the spherical cords is basically just math from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system. The nodes look like this:

[image]

The output of this node is going to be a field of values between -pi and pi, but  ColorRamp fac wants values between 0 and 1. So we need to remap this array. With some simple math we can also make an offset, so that we can animate the movement:
[image]

Comment: "*The base idea is still the same, make geometry nodes output some values, that you can then use in shading nodes*". I'm trying to understand how the value of attribute `distance` from the geometry tree of the 1st picture is recovered by the shader of the 2nd picture. Because `distance` appears nowhere in the shader, instead the shader attribute node refers to `new attribute`...?

Comment: In the geo-nodes modifier tab you add a name to output atribute, you use that name in the atribute node of shader editor.  Look at 2nd and 3rd picture of LuckyOnes solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how exactly you want to change the color, but with this easy GN nodes setup:

[image]

and this shader node setup:

[image]

and this modifier:

[image]

you get this:

[image]