# Geometry Nodes: Get Instance Scale?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to capture Scale like I am using Position below to capture Scale of Instances?

[image]

Comment: The 'Object Info' node has an (object level) scale output.. you can point that at the modified object.

Comment: @RobinBetts this is all entirely inside GNodes, there is no outside geometry unfortunately. I am scaling instances and then trying to capture scale per instance (after realizing them).

Comment: What version are you using? If you scale your instances, you already have a scale value and you only need to capture it, right? [Modify instance geometry based on the location of the instance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245804/modify-instance-geometry-based-on-the-location-of-the-instance/245858#245858)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thanks for the link that was helpful and also it looks like 3.1 resolves my issue! I was trying to use Instance Scale to pass curve radius to realized instances based on their position on the curve, now I can just use the Capture Attribute node directly in 3.1. The Transfer Attribute node did work, but because it uses proximity it was causing issues when the host curve was twisted too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just to be able to close this question, a short answer:*

Since you create all geometry with *Geometry Nodes*, you already have the corresponding value for *Scale* somewhere here.

According to your description, you influence the *Curve Radius* of the curve points with this value.

To get this value per instance after using `Realize Instances`, you would have to use the node `Capture Attributes` on the domain *Instances* before. If you actually control the scaling on instantiation directly using the `Radius` node, then you get this value using `Transfer Attributes`.

It might look like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>