# Geometry Nodes: How to make tube from curve

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

Given a curve node's output (in this case, a quadrilateral Bezier), how can I get a tube shape? I'm looking to make a rope from the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *Curve to Mesh* you get the desired mesh, but no mapping coordinates to be able to use your shader.

If you want/need to add seamless shading/texturing to your mesh generated with *Curve to Mesh*, follow this post: [Node "Curve to Mesh" with UVs in Blender 3.1?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258246/node-curve-to-mesh-with-uvs-in-blender-3-1)

Answer (score 12):

You can use a *Curve to Mesh* node and link another curve (for instance, a *Curve Circle* primitive) into the *Profile Curve* socket to sweep it along.

[image]

Comment: hi, what if i have a static curve object in the scene and i want to do use it as profile it in the geometry node? can this be done?

Comment: @adrianli You should be able to do that with an Object Info node. Select your curve from the scene in the dropdown, and link the Geometry output to the Profile Curve input on Curve to Mesh.