# Is there a way to have an adaptive uv on a curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, texture-coordinates

I am working on a rope sculpture where I will hand draw several curves. I have found an answer ([Texture coordinate on geometry nodes rope from Default Cube's tutorial (texture coordinates over profile curve)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252909/texture-coordinate-on-geometry-nodes-rope-from-default-cubes-tutorial-texture)) to how to add texture coordinates to a curve which has been super helpful. However, since I will be working with several curves of different lengths I need the texture coordinates to be uniform along the length of the curve.

As you can see the coordinates stretch along the curve in the photo.[image]

I would love to know if there is a way to create an adaptive texture coordinate along a curve.

[image]

Comment: This answer should help you solve the problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258247/145249

Comment: I have tried looking, however, I am have an extremely basic understanding of geometry nodes so it's no use to me yet.

Comment: a picture of your GN setup would be helpful

Comment: use the *length* output of the *spline parameter* node instead of the *factor*.

Comment: IMO, Default Cube's method is unnecessarily complicated for the cases it covers. I'm reluctant to post an answer here, because it is effectively a duplicate of the link given by quellenform above.  See how [this method](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jVSOLqz8/) suits you.

Comment: Thanks @shmuel, that worked :)