# How can I distort instances randomly using set position and noise?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I had this idea to make a flock of fish in geometry nodes by distributing them in volume. And to animate it using set position + noise. Looks ok-ish but all instances of fish move together in the same time and in same way.

Does anyone know a way to randomise their movement? Like you can randomize scale using random value, but for set position offset. So that each instance is distorted in a different way.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274486/19307 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245804/modify-instance-geometry-based-on-the-location-of-the-instance/263214#263214

Answer (score 0):

I think you should *realize instances* to convert instances to mesh and then set offset in *set position* node:

[image]